# How to Call APIs of libXYZ.so, from a ABC.jar file

Tags: java, static-libraries

I have an external static library (libXYZ.so)
I would like to implement a Jar file(ABC.jar) from which, have to call APIs mentioned in libXYZ.so.

Considering me as a starter in this area.
1. Is it feasible to achieve?
2. Could someone guide me the steps that needs to be done.
(If possible some temp code)

Comment: `libXYZ.so` is a shared library, not a static library.